# tags$style() or theme = "style.css" does not work when i use bs_theme()

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, r-markdown

I generated a html file by rmarkdown and set the theme as "theme: default". However, when I add this html file in a shiny app by "includeHTML("Help.html")", the style of this shiny app changed to the style controlled by "theme: default". I think this problem is like another one: tags$style() or theme = "style.css" does not work when I use bs_theme().

example:
The style was changed by

```html
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fixedPage(
    # theme = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "dark"),
    tags$style(HTML("
          .navbar .navbar-header {float: left; }
          .navbar .navbar-nav {float: right;}
          .container {min-width: 1200px}
           body > div > nav .nav.navbar-nav {
            float: right;
            font-size: 15px;
           }
           body > div > nav .navbar-brand {
            padding-left: 30px
           }
        ")
    ),
    navbarPage(
      windowTitle = "aaa",
      fluid = TRUE,
      title = "aaa",
      selected = "aaa",
      tabPanel("aaa"),
      tabPanel("aaa",),
      tabPanel("aaa"),
    ),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

When I used bs_theme() at the same time:

```html
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fixedPage(
    theme = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "dark"),
    tags$style(HTML("
          .navbar .navbar-header {float: left; }
          .navbar .navbar-nav {float: right;}
          .container {min-width: 1200px}
           body > div > nav .nav.navbar-nav {
            float: right;
            font-size: 15px;
           }
           body > div > nav .navbar-brand {
            padding-left: 30px
           }
        ")
    ),
    navbarPage(
      windowTitle = "aaa",
      fluid = TRUE,
      title = "aaa",
      selected = "aaa",
      tabPanel("aaa"),
      tabPanel("aaa",),
      tabPanel("aaa"),
    ),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

The style was absolutely controlled by bs_theme(). I want to make some chagnes based on the bs_theme() by tag$style. But when I used them at the same time, tag$style does not work.

I think the problem is caused by the priority of style parameters, but I do not know how to solve it.

Is there a way to make tags$style() or theme = "style.css" has higher priority than bs_theme?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal *reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your suggestion. I have added a minimal reproducible example.